# South migration for social auth

Tags: django, django-south, django-socialauth

I am using south in my django project. I just added social_auth in settings.py, when i run this command:
python manage.py schemamigration social_auth --auto

It says:**Nothing seems to have changed.**

Please let me know how can i create tables for social auth, as by this command the table is not getting created.

Comment: Have you actually verified that the tables do not exist yet?

Comment: Yes i verified it.. but it is working now.. by the command mentioned in the comment.   python manage.py migrate social_auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to generate migrations for social_auth, since this app should already have its migrations. Rather, you need to execute them, so after you added 'social_auth' in your settings you have to run only this command:

```
python manage.py migrate social_auth
```

Answer (score 3):

[django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) works perfectly except that it needs South and it doesn't work with newer versions of Django.

To remove the dependencies form South in django-social-auth, simply remove the migrations created by South and create new ones using the newer migration engine from Django 1.7 >.

This is how I fixed it:

```
# Install django (if you haven't) and django-social-auth
(my_venv)$ pip install django django-social-auth

# Delete the South migrations
# Using a virtual environment: my_venv
# In case you use python3, replace
(my_venv)$ rm <path_to_my_venv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/migrations/000*

# Create an dummy django project
(my_venv)$ django-admin startproject asdf
```

Add django-social-auth to the asdf/settings.py file

```
### asdf/asdf/settings.py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social_auth',
)
...
```

Finally create the new migration for django-social-auth

```
# Create new migrations
$ python asdf/manage.py makemigrations social_auth

# Delete the dummy django-project
$ rm -r asdf
```

This fix will work for all the Django projects that work under the same virtual environment.

Comment: This fixed it for me using django 1.8. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me! I have added a reference to your suggested solution here ( https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24524#comment:20 ).

Comment: django-social-auth is no longer maintained and it has been replaced in favor of python-social-auth [link](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth). Depending on your case, it is relatively simple to migrate from one platform to another and it is HIGHLY recommended :)